# How to get Beamer Math to look like Article Math

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode

In a LaTeX `article`, the math characters are more "curvy" than the text characters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
 $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$
\end{document}
```

[image: article math]

In a `beamer` presentation, the math characters do not have the same curves:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer math]

### Question

How can I get the `beamer` math to look just like the `article` math?

I would prefer if the solution was a single line (that I could place at the top of my LaTeX file) as opposed to something that needs to appear next to every piece of math.

Comment: Just a minor point: it is generally felt to be easier to read sans serif fonts when projected than serif fonts so the lack of curves is there for a reason.

Comment: @Andrew Sure, but I think that it is too difficult to tell the difference between what is text and what is math, especially when people are used to the `mathserif` font LaTeX articles but don't see that font on the slides.

Comment: Agreed.  I wasn't saying _Don't ever do this_ but rather _This is there for a reason_.  People reading this question might not realise that there is a reason for this choice and decide to change their maths to serif simply because that's what they're used to.  I happen to use colours to get round this problem so I'm in full agreement that it's good to do *something* to distinguish the maths from the text.

Comment: @Andrew Do you put all math in the same color or something more complicated?

Comment: Something more complicated.  The colour says what it is.  On the basis that a picture paints a thousand words, you can take a look at my beamer slides at the following URL: http://mathsnotes.math.ntnu.no/mathsnotes/show/lecture+notes+2011

Comment: @AndrewStacey, slightly off-topic, but do you find that the cyan projects well?  I remember a colloquium with colour-coded equations, and the important bit was in green on white and nobody could read it, even in the front row.

Comment: @ChrisH I guess it depends on the projector.  I did this in lectures where I was using the same projector each time and so could use feedback to figure out the right colour scheme.

Comment: @AndrewStacey it certainly does... though it often seems to be the ambient light level at the screen that makes the difference.

Comment: @LoopSpace I do think that nowadays it is much more acceptable to have the mathserif font appear on screen, mainly due to the improved resolutions and quality of projectors.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Add `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` to your preamble. That is,

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For both text and math in Computer Modern, use the `serif` document class option. Other combination of font selection is also possible. See [this link](http://faq.ktug.org/wiki/uploads/MathFonts.pdf) for a nicely compiled collection.

<sub>Older versions (prior to v3.33) supported the class option `\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}`.</sub>

Comment: +1, although I don't recommend this option that makes math conflict with the overall aspect of the presentation.

Comment: @egreg, what do you mean by the "conflict with the overall aspect of the presentation". It works perfectly for me and looks great.

Comment: @Lex Mixing "serif math" with a sans serif text font is something I wouldn't even think to use.

Comment: IM(unqualified)O this can look smarter than the class between different sans serif fonts that often happens because there aren't many full maths sans serif options, and the body is set in something else.

Comment: This class option is obsolete as of `beamer` v3.33. As recommended by the warning message, use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` instead in the current version of `beamer`.

Comment: Why the reference says `Who is going to use CMR in presentation? Should be avoided!`?

Comment: @stackunderflow: Without Computer Modern you're left with different fonts in the final document. Using `serif` leaves you with a single document font feel.

Comment: The link seems dead... is this: http://faq.ktug.org/wiki/uploads/MathFonts.pdf the same?

Answer (score 46):

Alternatively, you can include

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

inside the

```
mode<presentation>{...}
```

environment.

Comment: Actually this solution worked better for me: using the "serif" option does not properly replace the \nu-resembling "v" with the amsart curvy one.

Comment: You can also pass `[professionalfonts]` as an option to `\documentclass`.

Comment: This worked better for me. the `mathserif` was not exactly same font as the one in articles. This `professionalfonts` was exactly same as article math.

Comment: @HafezMousavi What's the difference? I get the same thing when I use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` as `\usepackage[mathfonts]{serif}`

Answer (score 9):

As @egreg commented, @Werner's answer might incur conflicts. Actually, Beamer supports for different fonts through the `\documentclass`.

In your case:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
...
```

for all other combinations and styles along with the outputs please refer to [this](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/MathFonts.pdf) comprehensive document.

Comment: Please note that the `mathserif` class option is obsolete.