# Beamer error - no output file

Tags: beamer

I am making a beamer file. While there's nothing in math mode, everything runs perfectly well, however, when sentences like

```
$P_A\subseteq E_X$
```

is inserted, it cannot output a `.pdf` file, but its ok with only `$\subseteq$`. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, could you construct a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv); start by *copying* your file, and then strip the copy until you have a minimal file that reproduces the error. Either this process will help you fix it, or you can post the minimal file and hopefully someone here can take a look :)

Comment: Are you loading the `amsmath` package?

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @Sigur: no, I didn't. But loading or not makes no difference.

Comment: With ]mathserif] added, the problem has been solved. Thanks for everyone! I am dumb :p

Comment: @Kuan: See [Fonts in `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38134/5764) where the suggestion is to rather use `usefonttheme[onlymath]{mathserif}`. However, I don't know why you are having problems...