# Configuring latex to use serif font by default when in math mode

Tags: fonts, beamer, math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Beamer Math to look like Article Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34265/how-to-get-beamer-math-to-look-like-article-math)

I have been playing around with TikZ and am impressed.

I have noticed that the $A$ math mode syntax is using sans serif, italicized font. How can I switch it to use serif, italicized font by default whenever in math mode?

Note: This is *not* TikZ specific. Regular math display mode appears to have the same issue.

**Update**

It is a beamer-specific setting and probably has something to do with the \usetheme[default} setting. I will now look into the theme itself, but if anyone knows the specific setting to override the sans serif behavior it would speed me up.

Comment: The default is serif. Do you use beamer?

Comment: The default math font is a serif italic, so the answer is don't do whatever you are doing that is changing it:-) Please supply a complete (small) example document that shows the problem, then it will be easier to give specific advice.

Comment: I am, indeed, using beamer. I took that out and made a simple \documentclass{article} and the math font is now serif. A question clarification is now in order.

Comment: \documentclass[mathserif]{beamer} achieves what I want. I will answer my own question once my mandatory 8 hour wait is done.