# Formatting capital letters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting, characters

This is perhaps a simple question, but I would like to print a capital `I` in my LaTeX document (`beamer` specifically) inside a `$...$` construct.  I would like my `I` to appear more substantial by having the horizontal lines at top and bottom, however this is not what I am getting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math fonts in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) are set in serif by default. To change this, see [How to get `beamer` math to look like `article` math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265/5764) (use the `mathserif` class option). On a case-by-case basis, you could use `$...\mathrm{I}...$` to obtain a serif-style `I`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  I \quad $I$ \quad $\mathrm{I}$ \quad $\textrm{I}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you're using this "I" on a more frequent and contextual-specific basis, consider using a macro like

```
\newcommand{\upshapeI}[1]{\textrm{\upshape I}}
```

The above suggestions follows the principles in [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).