# how can I modify the font of just the formulas in TeXLive?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, texlive

For sure it's a really silly question, but I can't find a solution: how can I change the font of just the formulas in a TeXLive document?

I want a style where the "f" (for "function") is elegant, slim, tall, a bit oblicuous and with serifs, similar to a little integral sign, and the "a" is nearly a circle, like this one:

[image]

Instead, I get a really awful style, with an "f" too litle and fat.

[image]

Does somebody know the name of the font and how can I change it?

All the best and thanks a lot!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Also a minimal example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that exhibits the problem would be very useful.

Comment: The image suggests you're doing a `beamer` document.

Comment: sounds like this one would be related: [How to get Beamer Math to look like Article Math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265)

Comment: [This page](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html) shows you what various math fonts look like.

Comment: yes, I'm using beamer in debian 7. Thanks a lot, guys: I have just added the mathserif document option to beamer, as suggested by the link posted by @cmhughes, and now the formula look pretty nice. All the best!!