# Why, in Beamer, letters written in math mode look as written in normal mode

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode

I'm making a presentation with `beamer` and have noticed that letters written in math mode look exactly the same as letters written in normal mode; in other words `$K$` looks in the PDF exactly like `K`, while when you write a paper using, for example, `article` letters in math mode look italicized. Why is this happening? In case you wonder, my preamble is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}


\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{ejem}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is by design. If you wish to change it so that math-mode content reverts to the regular article-based format, see [How to get `beamer` math to look like `article` math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265/5764).