# Switch from phv to cmr in math mode using beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, pdftex

In my `beamer` document I am unable to switch to `cmr` for formulae since they look weird otherwise.

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{mybeamer} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Normal Text.
  {\myfont
    \begin{equation*}
      f(x) = \sin(x)
    \end{equation*}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

mybeamer class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mybeamer}[2010/12/30 v0.5]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}

\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{beamer}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10.5pt}{12.5pt}\xiiiv}

\DeclareFixedFont{\x}{T1}{phv}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFixedFont{\xb}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{10}
\newfont{\xiiiv}{phvr8t at 30pt}
\newfont{\xiiivb}{phvb8t at 8.5pt}
```

How can I make this font change happen?

Comment: Have a look here [How to get Beamer Math to look like Article Math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Johannes_B I had a closer look at the `beamer` [documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=192&zoom=auto,0,537) and found out that the command

```
\LoadClass[mathserif]{beamer}
```

will make the math-mode look like the one in an article.

Comment: Well, to be honest, you are more flexible when using `\documentclass[mathserif]{mybeamer}`. But as @egreg said in the aforementioned thread: The result of serif maths and sans serif text is *just ugly*.

Comment: Why is your solution more flexible?

Comment: You can choose to give the option to `mybeamer`. If you load `beamer` out of `mybeamer`, the mathserif is *hardwired*.