# XeLaTeX/beamer/fontspec/unicode-math: Change font of all math digits

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, unicode-math, mathspec

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{some-font.otf}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text with the number \textit{two} in text mode (2) and math mode ($2$).
        \begin{equation*}
            \vec{s}(t) = \frac{\vec{a}}{2} t^2 + \vec{v}_0 t + \vec{s}_0
        \end{equation*}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How to change the font of all math digits to the sans font defined with [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)'s `\setsansfont` command (font-independent)?

I tried to experiment with the `\Umathcode` XeTeX primitive as well as with `\setmathfont` provided by [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), however, I had no success.

I am aware of the package [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) and its `\setmathfont(digits)` command, but I realized that the combination of a [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) class document and `fontspec`/`mathspec` causes misplaced math elements (see figures 1 and 2 for a comparison; for figure 2, `\usepackage{unicode-math}` package has been commented out in the MWE).

[image: Figure 1: With <code>unicode-math</code> loaded.]
[image: Figure 2: Without <code>unicode-math</code>.]

**Update:**
This MWE compiles without any error in my setup. However, if the line `\setmainfont{Arial}` is commented out, an error will be thrown. The same is true if I specify a font as a file (*.ttf or *.otf) instead of a system-installed font.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont[range={\mathup}]{Lucida Sans}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{equation}
            x = \int\limits_0^\infty f(q) \,\mathrm{d} q
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How to get `beamer` math to look like `article` math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265/5764)

Answer (score 5):

Disable the font setting of `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% use own font handling
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit}]{Lucida Sans Italic}
\setmathfont[range={\mathup}]{Lucida Sans}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text with the number \textit{two} in text mode (2) and math mode ($2$).
        \begin{equation*}
            \vec{s}(t) = \frac{\vec{a}}{2} t^2 + \vec{v}_0 t + \vec{s}_0
        \end{equation*}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your solution is a first step in the right direction, however, I am missing three important things: (i) The math font should be the default LaTeX one and I don't know how to set this with `\setmathfont`. (ii) Only math digits shall be set to the main font defined with `fontspec`, without recalling the font name manually. (iii) Additionally, the equation seems misplaced (distance of elements), which I do not want.

Comment: If you didn't define a math font Computer Modern will be used. The `range` option can also be used for defining the sequence 0..9.

Comment: Not defining a main font does not work for me in some cases. Please try the MWE in the _Update_ section of my original question.

Comment: `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}` for the default setting, which is like Computer Modern Math

Comment: When I use this setting, my document compiles. However, (i) using Latin Modern Math, despite it is quite similar to Computer Modern, causes misplaced limits for integrals with 8pt as beamer option, (ii) this solution still throws an error if I want to use font files instead of system-installed fonts.