# Set Math Font like in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode

How can I set the Beamer math font in a non-Beamer class (e.g., article)?

The motivation is that I prepare a poster and a presentation for a workshop which I would like to look as similar as possible, i.e. both should have a "Beamer style".

Comment: Related: [How to get `beamer` math to look like `article` math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265/5764)

Comment: Beamer uses the `\sfdefault`, the sans-serif default family, which is Computer Modern Sans. So just `\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.

Comment: @Werner Related in the sense of opposite problem. Unfortunately, I do not see how the suggestions there should help here.

Comment: @AndrewCashner This only works for the text font, not the math font.

Comment: @gTcV: That's why it's *related*, nothing else...

Comment: Sorry, I think this should do it: `\renewcommand*{\mathfamilydefault}{\sfdefault}` (see `beamer.cls`, lines 255-256)

Comment: @AndrewCashner As far as I can tell, that is a `beamer` command and attempting to redefine it that way in `article` will just give an error. Moreover using `\newcommand*` instead, while it wouldn't give you an error, would not, just in itself, have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given [Andrew Cashner's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222812/set-math-font-like-in-beamer#comment523003_222812), I think you probably just need the `sfmath` package. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
  3x^7i + \sqrt{9}{y} = \cos z^4
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer-style maths?]

Answer (score 3):

Three choices with “real” sans serif math fonts.

### Option 1, Arev fonts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arevmath,arevtext}
\begin{document}
Some text before the display
\[
3x^7i + \sqrt{9}{y} = \cos z^4
\]
and after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 2, Helvetica

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{tgheros}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}
\begin{document}
Some text before the display $y$
\[
3x^7i + \sqrt{9}{y} = \cos z^4
\]
and after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 3, Iwona

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\begin{document}
Some text before the display $y$
\[
3x^7i + \sqrt{9}{y} = \cos z^4
\]
and after.
\end{document}
```

[image]