# Beamer template setbeamerfont bfseries

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, templates, bold

I have a problem regarding the `\setbeamerfont` command related to alerted text. The usage is:

```
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}
```

However, bfseries does not work in math mode - what can I do to obtain the same effect for alerted text in math mode?

To use `\bf` was one thing I found during my search, but `\bf` is deprecated and should not be used, as it was told to be unstable in certain cases.

Minimal example:

beamerthemeTest.sty:

```
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}
\mode
<all>
```

Document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \alert{This text is alerted.}
  \alert{$x^2$} cannot be alerted.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: question already answered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34265/how-to-get-beamer-math-to-look-like-article-math

Comment: @aronadaal I don't see how this solves my problem, please elaborate further

Comment: sry, I was a bit too fast. Here is now a working example.

Comment: The difference between the added `theme` and the answer below, is that here you load `mathptmx`.  This does not have a bold version of math, and anyway is regard as obselete, see [https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx?lang=en].  If instead you either omit this package (so you get standard fonts) or use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` (times like) then the solution provided works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I was a bit too fast with my answer. Use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` for serif font in math mode and `\boldmath` for bold font - again only in math mode.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  $ x = 5 - 2 $
\column{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \boldmath
  $ x = 5 - 2 $
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:
Ok, now with the your example I understand the problem. Solves this one your problem?

The theme:

```
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}
\mode
<all>
```

The document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \alert{This text is alerted.}
  \alert{$x^2$} can be alerted, too! % math inside \alert{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay - but how do I set this inside a beamertemplate? Maybe I was not precise enough: What I want is that whenever I use '\alert{Stuff}' I want _Stuff_ to be bold and colored, no matter which mode I am in

Comment: please provide a working/non-working minimal example http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html

Comment: Ok, extended the question

Comment: answer extended, too

Comment: Okay, this removes the error, but in my case the font is not bold - I will figure that out and report.

Comment: did you see that I modified the theme too?
--> \setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}

Comment: yes, I included that in my theme, which fixed the error, but I couldn't really see a difference in the font -> I assume this might be related to the fonttheme (although I've tried default)?

Comment: can you post a working example or your code again? so I can have a look...

Comment: Okay, I've included all of the template, that is related to fonts, the rest is just some template elements and color definitions.

Comment: and where is the `\boldmath` definition inside your beamerstyle? You have to replace this line `\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}` by this one `\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}`

Did you really have a look at my answer?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that in the edit - Yes, I've tried your solution, but it does not seem to produce bold text (I am sure you've tested it yourself, so I assume, that there is a different problem, which I still cannot figure out)

Comment: @Modass See my comment on your modified question regarding font choices.