# Psi is different in beamer and usual tex documents

Tags: beamer, symbols

I don't know why, but the `\Psi` char displayed in beamer is different from the `Psi` in usual tex files:

what I want/have in classic tex files:

[image]

What I have in Beamer:

[image]

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  $\Psi$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beamer uses as default a sans-serif font. Search for how to use serif fonts in beamer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use this few times, you can do `$\mathrm{\Psi}$`. But, if you want to use serif fonts in whole document, use

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

As pointed out by Medina [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263892/14757) you can use serif fonts only in math mode using the option

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

[image][image]