# \Phi looks bad in Beamer

Tags: symbols

I'm making a beamer presentation.
If I write $\Phi$ it kind of looks bad in beamer, like shown below. I want a better looking $\Phi$ like in article.
[image: I don't want like this][image: I want like this]

Comment: Just sayin'...the `\Phi` in beamer is consistent with a sans serif font.  The default article shape differs in that it has serifs on the center strut, consistent with the rest of the default computer modern math font found in article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34265/how-to-get-beamer-math-to-look-like-article-math

Comment: I would also add that, in general, sans serif fonts are easier to read at longer distances, such as one finds the situation during screen presentations.  This would explain why beamer (a screen presentation documentclass) defaults to sans serif alphabets.

Comment: Indeed, it looks better on the screen

Comment: Accordingly, in the modern day of making slideshows for Zoom presentations which the audience will watch on their own computer screens, there is no reason to use a sans serif font (and I recommend switching to serif at least for math mode).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather that import a different `\Phi`, which will in general not be compatible in style with the pre-existing font, I instead here choose to add small serifs to the existing rendering of `\Phi`, calling it `\altPhi`.  I have made it work in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\altPhi{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{
  \stackengine{-.6\LMpt}{%
  \stackengine{-.7\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\Phi}{\rule{.5\LMex}{.7\LMpt}\kern.01ex}
    {U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}%
  {\rule{.5\LMex}{.7\LMpt}\kern.01ex}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Phi \altPhi$
$\scriptstyle\Phi \altPhi$
$\scriptscriptstyle\Phi \altPhi$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

With the `professionalfonts` class option, you can load the font of your choice.  Your options include:

- Any OpenType font with `unicode-math`.  You can even add the `\Phi` symbol from another font with `\setmathfont[range=\mupPhi]{SomeFont.otf}` (If you select `math-style=ISO`, which gives you slanted uppercase Greek letters, you would override `\mitPhi` instead of `\mupPhi`.)
- Any OML-encoded font with `isomath`
- Any LGR-encoded font with `mathastext`
- Any math font package
- Any OT1-encoded font, with `\DeclareMathAlphabet`. (These have uppercase, but not lowercase, Greek letters.)

If you can choose which compiler and packages to use, I would recommend that you use `unicode-math` with a sans-serif font such as Fira Math, and compile with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

You can switch using `mathastext` package with the options `italic` and `symbolgreek`: but the Greek symbol are in `upright` mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[italic,symbolgreek]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\Phi_n(x)=\prod_{\zeta \text{ primitive }}{(x-\zeta)}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]