# How do I get boldface math letters into beamer?

Tags: beamer, math-fonts

How do I get a boldface math letters into beamer? The following produces an italic F and a non-italic F.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title} $F \mathbf{F}$ \textbf{F} \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title} $F \mathbf{F}$ \textbf{F} \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If use article instead, I get what I am used to see:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$F \mathbf{F}$ \textbf{F} 
\end{document}
```

I guess the broader question is how to change math fonts in beamer (without breaking anything), and I'd appreciate your answer to that as well.

EDIT: added `\textbf{F}` for comparison.

Comment: This is what I get for your MWE: *F* **F** (as expected)

Comment: If you give `beamer` the `professionalfonts` option, you can load any font package of choice. Also, if you’re using `beamer`, you are not submitting a paper to one of the remaining publishers who still require PDFTeX in 2021, so you are free to switch to LuaLaTeX and load an OpenType font.

Comment: Related: [How to get Beamer Math to look like Article Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Well, I don't. I just compared it with plain \textbf{F}.

Comment: @shuhalo: Can you post your `.log` from compiling the MWE? It should highlight any font substitutions, if that occurred.

Comment: @Werner: the log file is too big. Should I grep something in particular?

Comment: @shuhalo: Remove content (packages and unnecessary suff) from your original file until you can replicate the issue. Then you can post that, smaller, `.log` (and accompanying code).

Comment: @Werner: I am afraid it already is my MWE. Latex definite states that there have been font substitutions.

Comment: @shuhalo: [Here is my `.log`](https://pastebin.com/raw/wtRkj2Ft), for reference.