# Numbers are not displayed correctly in Feather Theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I am using [Modified feather beamer theme](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modified-feather-beamer-theme-theme/hprfhrqkbzqq) template by overleaf. It doesn't display the numbers in a "correct format" ([image: 1]) even by using $1$. It has an undesirable format ([image: 2]).

I have tried to look into the theme and other files but unable to fix it.

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with 'correct format'? The theme does display numbers when I try it, and it looks reasonable in my opinion.

Comment: @Marijn, I have edited the question. Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: It is default in beamer (in all styles, not just Feather) that math is in this type of font (i.e., sans serif). You could try the solutions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34265/how-to-get-beamer-math-to-look-like-article-math.

Comment: @Marijn, I have earlier used other the Madrid and Metropolis theme. I didn't have such problems. Also, the solutions in the link are not working for me. :(

Comment: If I use `\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}  
\usetheme{Feather}` then the numbers change (only in math, so `$12345$` changes but `12345` stays the same). Does that not work when you try it?

Comment: @Marijn I don't know why, but it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: And does it work now, or does it still not work?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. Finally, [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161390/191472) worked for me. I added external code to the theme for image fitting and some other stuff. I commented that and It worked.

Comment: Ok, let's close as a duplicate then.