# Weird caligraphy in Mathbb fonts

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I would like to include a chalkboard alphabet font. However, when I do that the fonts look very tacky, I would like something more stylish. See pictures for reference:

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, below an MWE:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % --> loads xcolor and hyperref

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Loaded by default in beamer (and many others...)
%\usepackage{
%   amsthm
%   color
%   enumerate
%   fourier
%   hyperref
%   xcolor
%   graphicx        % A more advanced package for images and figures
%}

\usepackage{
    fourier,            % For typesetting
    newtxtext,      % To set the fonts to Times New Roman
    import,         % to import files
    caption,            % To include captions in tables and figures
    subcaption,     % To include subcaptions in tables and figures  
    float,          % Improves floating objects: figures and tables
    nicematrix,         % To make nice tables
    multicol,       % For multicolum slides
    ragged2e,       % New commands and environments for ragged tex
    mathtools,      % Loads and enhances the features of amsmath
    amssymb,            % Enhances symbols in math environment
    cancel,         % to cross a term in an equation
    marvosym,       % Adds Marting Vogel's symbols: euro, comunicaiton,...
}                   
    
%TO BE REMOVED
    %\let\marvosymLightning\Lightning   
    %This sequence of packages controls the mathematical tools of latex
            %\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}  % to cross a term in an equation



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% START OF THE PRESENTATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
 
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{align*}
                \mathbb{NE}
        \end{align*}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you find it weird? beamer is generally  sans serif, and certainly if you draw an |E on the blackboard (which is what the name refers to) it will look more like your first image than your second. Although you can of course change the fonts.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response, how can I do that?

Comment: well it depends a bit if you just want to change just mathbb or all fonts (eg use newtxmath as well as newtxtext) there is probably answer here on choosing beamer math fonts, I'll add a suitable link if I see one. You are choosing both fourier and newtxtext at the same time which is rather odd the main font can't be Times and Utopia at the same time.

Comment: see for example the file linked from this answer for lots of possibilities https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34267/1090